# Zend_Form jQuery slider

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, slider, zend-form

How to make jQuery slider with fixed maximum ... exact like this:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#rangemin

I manage to do it half way:

```
$slider = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_Slider('amount');
$slider->setLabel('Set Amount: ');
$slider->setJQueryParams(array('min' => 0, 'max' => 60, 'value' => 15));
```

I don't know how to display the value since it has its own code:

```
$(function() {
  $("#amount-slider").slider({
   range: "min",
   value: 15,
   min: 1,
   max: 60,
                        // !!! HOW TO
   slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#amount").val('$' + ui.value);
   }
  });
  // !!! HOW TO
                $("#amount").val('$' + $("#amount-slider").slider("value"));
});
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're after, you want a fixed maximum, different than the 60 your specifying?

Comment: No, I want to have a jquery code as it is in the showcase http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#rangemin. Zendx will generate some code, but i need the liberty to add more functionality (add a function...).

Comment: If you've solved the problem, don't put it in your question, answer your own question!

Comment: @Yi Jiang.  I stand corrected. I made the correction. My solution is offered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

I solved my problem with selectToUISlider.jQuery.js plugin for jQuerySlider, it will hijack the select tag that you define in Form class. So just call like:

```
$('select').selectToUISlider();
```

Really elegant solution.

Here is the link:

<strike>http://www.jquerylabs.com/selecttouislider-plugin.html</strike>

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_ui_16_slider_from_a_select_element/

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery code is added in [ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper_Slider](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/extras/trunk/library/ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/Slider.php). Replace it with a custom implementation and use it instead of the regular ViewHelper.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$slider->setJQueryParams(array(
  'min' => 0,
  'max' => 60,
  'value' => 15,
  'slide' => new Zend_Json_Expr('function(event, ui) {
    $("#amount").val('$' + ui.value);
   }')
));
```